# how to in a observable find and move item to top of collection

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

New to Rxjs. I am familiar with pipe, filter, sort , map etc but not able to get this problem. I need to find an item in my observable returned data and move it to the top before it displays. In this example Darth Vader is item 4 and I want to find and move to 0th or first position in observable array/collection.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/findandmakefirst

Comment: So, use the map() operator, and use it to transform the array you receive into an array containing the same elements in the order you want. And please, don't use the `any`type. Define an interface describing the objects you receive. Using proper types will help you understand what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
people$ = this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/')
  .map((res:any) => {
    var _vader = res.results.splice(res.results.findIndex(x => x.name === 'Darth Vader'), 1);
    return [..._vader, ...res.results];
  });
```

Comment: Your answer has helped me very much 4 years later. Thank you good sir!

Answer (score 1):

```
import { People } from './sw-people.model';

interface Results {
  count: Number,
  next: String,
  previous: string,
  results: People[],
}

@Injectable()
export class SwPeopleService {
    people$ = this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/')
      .map((res: Results) => {
         return res.results.sort((a: People, b: People) => {
           return a.name === "Darth Vader" ? -1 : b.name === "Darth Vader" ? 1 : 0;
         });
        });

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {} 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a more detailed answer.